# Android keyboard obscures EditText

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-edittext

In my application, when I click on an EditText view, the virtual keyboard obscures the view, so I can't see my edits. How can I resolve this programatically?

Answer (score 11):

I recommend [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) that covers the various modes for how the IME and the underlying activity interact from a UI layering perspective. Without knowing more about your application, it is impossible to state whether you want resizing or "pan and scan" modes.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, It happens to me, But I solve it

```
    <activity
        ...............
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
    </activity>
```